# Why is the voltage across the inputs of an ideal OP Amp zero?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

The property that the voltage across the inputs of an ideal OP Amp is zero cannot be taken as an axiom because it isn't a property you can directly "adjust" (as opposed to say the resistance across the input terminals or the gain). It's a consequence of the properties that you can "adjust", hence it must be derived from these properties.

All proofs I've come across essentially prove it like this:

> Let the voltage across the input terminals of an ideal OP Amp be \$V_{in}\$, the output voltage be \$V_o\$ and the gain be \$G\$. \$V_o\$ is given by:
>
> \$V_o = GV_{in}\$
>
> The voltage across the OP Amp is bounded by the voltage being supplied to it. Let the supplied voltage be \$V_s\$. Then
>
> \$-V_s \le GV_{in} \le +V_s \$
>
> The gain is a property than can ideally be fixed to any value, so taking the limit of \$G\$ going to infinity gives:
>
> \$ \lim_{G \to \infty} \frac{-V_s}{G} \le V_{in} \le \frac{+V_s}{G} \$
>
> \$\implies 0 \le V_{in} \le 0\$
>
> Hence the voltage across the input terminals of an ideal OP Amp must be zero.

The proof above would only be valid if OP Amps were always linear, which isn't true. If the output is greater in magnitude than the supplied voltage, the OP Amp becomes saturated - the proof doesn't take this into account. In other words, the proof assumes that \$V_o = GV_{in}\$ which is false. The correct equation would be:

\$V_o = \begin{cases} GV_{in}, \space -V_{s} \le GV_{in} \le +V_{s} \\ +Vs, \space GV_{in} > V_s \\ -Vs, \space GV_{in} < -V_s \end{cases}\$

Comment: The emitters of the differential input transistors are tied together.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I haven't studied transistors yet, but from what I understand you're saying that both terminals are part of the same node. If this is the case, wouldn't the resistance across the terminals be \$0\$? Different from the assumed input resistance of infinity?

Comment: The voltage differential is zero only when negative feedback is employed. The amplifier does not have to be linear. And the proof is about *ideal* amplifier which does not saturate.

Comment: No, because one of the transistors acts as a reverse-biased diode. The inputs are on the bases.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Is there an explanation of it independent of the transistors inside? I was hoping for a proof that treats the OP Amp as a black box.

Comment: @venny The Wikipedia page on [ideal OP amps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Ideal_op-amps) says nothing about them not saturating.

Comment: @FarhadYusufali Actually it does: *Infinite voltage range available at the output*

Comment: Read @JonRB 's answer it points out the flaw in your logic.  The differential voltage across the inputs is not axiomatic, it is a result of negative feedback.  In fact even with an ideal op-amp you can have feedback configurations that cause oscillation - which is proof that the voltage is NOT zero.

Answer (score 4):

You misunderstood the "axiom"

An Ideal opamp will do what it can to make the differential voltage between the -ve pin and the +ve pin equal zero. It doesn't state it is zero

All it can do is alter its output and thus with negative feedback there OPAMP stands a chance of making the difference zero

You then make use of that fact during circuit analysis to simplify calculations "if the difference is zero and the +ve terminal is at 0V, then the output must be...)

Answer (score 2):

You did say "ideal" in the title of your question. Ideal opamps do not saturate.

And the assertion is only true if the opamp is in a circuit that incorporates negative feedback. The feedback causes the opamp to drive one of the inputs until it matches the other input. Since the (open-loop) gain of an ideal opamp is infinite, the resulting difference in the input voltages is infinitesimal (indistinguishable from zero).

Obviously, if a real opamp has a limited voltage swing, it does not have high gain when it saturates, and the assertion is no longer true. The input voltages will differ from each other by a sometimes considerable amount. Note that many opamps can take a surprisingly long time to recover from this condition; that's why they don't make good high-speed comparators.

Answer (score 1):

I think, it`s helpful to start with a real opamp. More than that, speaking about gain we always assume that the device is in its LINEAR region. Because of the large open-loop gain **Aol** opamps always are operated as linear amplifiers with negative feedback only.

Negative feedback has the property to produce a kind of stable balance (eqilibrium) between input and output. That means: The output voltage **Vout** causes a voltage drop across the feedback path that leads to a differential input voltage of exactly the value **Vd=Vout/Aol**. Of course, for large Aol the voltage Vd will be very small (µV range).
With other words: For a real opamp Vd never will be zero.

However, in many cases it is allowed to assume Vd=0. (This is equivalent to the assumption Aol infinite). This drastically simplifies the analysis of such amplifiers with feedback. It is allowed (and helpful) because the resulting error in gain calculation is much lower than other uncertainties (resistor tolerances). But it is important to keep in mind that this holds only up to a certain frequency limit (depending on the opamp type). As soon as the open-loop gain Aol falls below - let`s say - 40 dB, we have to consuider real opamp properties (finite gain).