# How the Req derived at inverting input?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog

I've been following TI precision lab, I didn't understand how the Req is derived. Can somebody explain, I am curious to know.

[image: This is the circuit]

[image: Derived equation]

Comment: Go study virtual op-amp earth and state what in the pictures Req is.

Answer (score 0):

Step by step help:

1. You are calculating the effect of the input bias current *I<sub>B</sub>*. Where can that flow to and what voltage will that cause?

> My understanding is that current will only able to flow through RF into the non-inverting input of the op-amp. since R1 will be at the same potential.

Have a look at my answer to [OpAmp used as adder](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/234062/opamp-used-as-adder) where I try to explain that the "virtual ground" will be not quite zero so current will, in fact, flow through R1. Now you've got two current paths. What is their combined resistance?

Respond in the comments and I'll update.

Comment: My understanding is that current will only able to flow through RF into the non-inverting input of the op-amp. since R1 will be at the same potential. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: sorry, I read the post, but I still don't understand, you're saying real op-amp virtual ground is not perfectly ground? Is there any model that we can use to derive?